# What is difference between Fmp4 and segmented mp4 . Can both be used as container for DASH/HLS playback?

Tags: fmp4

I wanted to know the difference between fmp4 (fragmented MP4) and the segmented Mp4 . Also how they are used in DASH/HLS playback.

Comment: Please share more details. Is this in any way related to programming?

Comment: probably duplicate, [HLS, fragmented mp4 or mpeg-ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905910)

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can, fmp4 segments work with DASH and HLS. Also called .m4s files

Cheers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).